# SQL Trigger After Update Insert data into another table

Tags: sql, triggers, insert

I have two table. One is customer_info and another one is update_log. I want to create a trigger that will execute after update in customer_info. If `cust_name, Contact` is updated then `cust_no, Cust_name, Contact, Date` will be added to second table. Second table will have two row with old data and new data. my code is not working. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER  update_trigger
AFTER UPDATE  ON CUSTOMER_info
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.cust_name <> OLD.cust_name || NEW.contact <> OLD.contact then
    insert into update_log values 
    ( OLD.cust_no,OLD.cust_name, OLD.contact, CURRENT_DATE); 

    insert into update_log  values
    ( NEW.cust_no,NEW.cust_name, NEW.contact,CURRENT_DATE);                 
  END IF
END
```

Comment: Tag please - Is this MySql? And please qualify "Not working" - errors, etc. Try specifying the columns explictly, i.e. `INSERT INTO UPDATE_LOG(col1, col2, ...) VALUES (...)` - they might not be in the order you've assumed.

Answer (score 1):

If You use MSSQL, You can use that trigger:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER  update_trigger
ON CUSTOMER_info 
FOR update AS

    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE (cust_name) OR UPDATE (contact)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO update_log (
                cust_no
                ,Cust_name
                ,Contact
                ,Date
                )
            SELECT cust_no
                ,cust_name
                ,contact
                ,GetDate()
            FROM INSERTED

            INSERT INTO update_log (
            cust_no
            ,Cust_name
            ,Contact
            ,Date
            )
        SELECT cust_no
            ,cust_name
            ,contact
            ,GetDate()
            FROM DELETED
        END
END
GO
```